# Parse a money String with decimal and grouping separator or throw if Pattern does not match

Tags: java

I wonder if there is a Class or Library that allows me to:

- define a decimal separator
- define a grouping separator
- define a grouping size
- parse a String into a BigDecimal or Double
- throw an exeption if the decimal separator, the grouping separator, or the grouping size does not match

The reason behind this is that I need to parse money values from a file
and the formatting of these might change. If it does change I need to avoid parsing wrong numbers.

Example:

- In File foo.csv the values are formatted with a dot as grouping separator and a comma as decimal separator e.g. `1.234,54`.
- In a newer File bar.csv the same number is formatted without grouping separator and dot as decimal separator: `1234.54`.
- When bar.csv is parsed an Exception should be thrown, since it excpects the pattern of foo.csv.

What I tried was using Decimal Format, but it does not work as I expected:

```
    @Test
    void testDecimalFormatParsing() throws ParseException {
        DecimalFormatSymbols sfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
        sfs.setDecimalSeparator(',');
        sfs.setGroupingSeparator('.');
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.###", sfs);
        decimalFormat.setGroupingUsed(true);
        decimalFormat.setGroupingSize(3);
        decimalFormat.setParseBigDecimal(true);

        assertEquals(0, parseMoney(decimalFormat, "1.234,56").compareTo(new BigDecimal("1234.56")));
        assertThrows(ParseException.class, () -> parseMoney(decimalFormat, "1234.56"));
    }

    private BigDecimal parseMoney(final DecimalFormat decimalFormat, final String originalValue) throws ParseException {
        final ParsePosition position = new ParsePosition(0);
        BigDecimal parsedValue = (BigDecimal) decimalFormat.parse(originalValue, position);
        boolean isParsedSuccesfully = position.getErrorIndex() == -1 && position.getIndex() == originalValue.length();

        System.out.println(originalValue + " -> " + parsedValue + " result: "
                + (isParsedSuccesfully ? "success" : "failure"));

        if (!isParsedSuccesfully) {
            throw new ParseException(originalValue, position.getIndex());
        } else {
            return parsedValue;
        }
    }
```

This returns:

```
1.234,56 -> 1234.56 result: success
1234.56 -> 123456 result: success


org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected java.text.ParseException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.
```

It just ignores the grouping size, the result is a hundred times bigger than it should be. Since it doesn't throw an Exception no one would notice.

I guess my next approach would be using Regex. I just wonder if I used DecimalFormat wrong? Or do you know a better way to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: The grouping size is ignored while parsing. It is used while generating a number.

Comment: Yes, I noticed numbers like `1.23.4,56` can be parsed as well. The question is if there is a way to avoid that.

Answer (score -2):

When you check the source of `DecimalFormat#parse(...)` ([source openjdk](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/739769c8fc4b496f08a92225a12d07414537b6c0/src/java.base/share/classes/java/text/DecimalFormat.java#L2141)) and especially `DecimalFormat#subparse(...)` ([source openjdk](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/739769c8fc4b496f08a92225a12d07414537b6c0/src/java.base/share/classes/java/text/DecimalFormat.java#L2285)), then you'll notice that it doesn't consider the grouping size. Instead it is mainly used when formatting a given number.

Two other options to verify the number instead can be:

- regex
- format the parsed number to see if it matches the original value

The latter approach would be as simple as:

```
boolean isParsedSuccessfully = decimalFormat.format(parsedValue).equals(originalValue);
```

Using that instead of your initial approach would result with these test value:

```
parseMoney(decimalFormat, "1.234,56");
parseMoney(decimalFormat, "1.234.567.890,12");
parseMoney(decimalFormat, "1234.56,0");
parseMoney(decimalFormat, "1.2.3.4.56,0");
```

this result:

> 1.234,56 -> 1234.56 result: success
> 1.234.567.890,12 -> 1234567890.12 result: success
> 1234.56,0 -> 123456.0 result: failure
> 1.2.3.4.56,0 -> 123456.0 result: failure